# Why in react-router v6.14 when I go to a link in a nav bar am I unable to go to a different link in same nav bar?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a nav bar hamburger style drop down list inside my header of my app that navigates to a variety of different pages:

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

interface dropNavPropTypes {
  forums: string[];
}

export default function DropDownNav({ forums }: dropNavPropTypes) {
  return (
    <nav id="drop-down-nav">
      {forums.map((name, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={`${name}-${index}`}>
            <NavLink to={`r/${name}`}>{`r/${name}`}</NavLink>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

I am able to select an item on the list and navigate to the appropriate page from different URLs (Home, CreateForum), but I am unable to go to a different page inside the drop down list when I am already in one of the links. I can see the anchor tag in the chrome dev tools and able to click on the href link but when I try to select it on the drop down menu it does not redirect or show a cursor that I can select the link. I am able to go to different pages from my header I just am unable to go to anything on my nav drop down list. This is how my routes are set up:

```
    <>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route
            path="create-forum"
            element={<CreateForum createForum={createForum} />}
          />{" "}
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/login/sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="r/:id">
          <Route index element={<Forum />} />
          <Route
            path="create-message"
            element={<CreateMessage createMessage={createMessage} />}
          />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
```

This is how my header is set up were the nav drop down component is located:

```
  return (
    <div id="header">
      <div id="title">
        <img src={mainIcon} alt="site symbol" />
        <h3>Fake Forum</h3>
      </div>

      <div id="search-items">
        <div id="drop-down-menu">
          <div id="icons">
            <Link to="/">
              <div id="home-icons">
                <img src={home} alt="home icon" />
                <div>Home</div>
              </div>
            </Link>
            <img src={chevronDown} alt="expand menu" onClick={showNav} />
          </div>
          {showDropDownNav ? <DropDownNav forums={forumNames} /> : null}
        </div>
        <div id="search-bar">
          <img src={magnify} />
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="user-icons">
        <Link to="/create-forum">
          <div id="add-forum">+</div>
        </Link>
        <button id="login-btn">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have it set up where if you click an icon on the header it pulls the names of the links from firebase using a useEffect hook and changes a state value that will show the nav bar when true.

I tried to rearrange the link and Li elements where the Li element is inside the NavLink. I also tried to switch to a normal Link from the react-router-dom. I even attempted to create a normal anchor element with a href but I still has the same exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown menu is possibly positioned behind other elements on the page, preventing it from receiving click events. You can try adding a higher z-index CSS property to the dropdown menu to ensure it appears above other elements.